# JSON-Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json

I'm facing a problem with linking JSON-Java library in Intellij IDEA.

When I try to start a server, it shows me `ClassNotFoundException` along with `NoClassDefFoundError`. However, IDEA doesn't show any errors before compilation.

I tried both using Maven dependencies and linking the .jar file in IDE but it didn't solve my problem.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Компания 1\":{\"Заказы\":\"4\", \"Счет\":\"1500.65\"}\"}");
      int orders = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("Заказы").toString());
      double money = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.get("Счет").toString());
      companyList.add(new Company(orders, money, null));

} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try invalidating your project cache. In the toolbar, click `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart`. IDEA will re-index everything. It would also help if you attached a screenshot of the library settings to your question.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, I'm trying to use Gson now. Anyway, thank you for help!

Comment: You have to deploy your libraries to the server too. Either in your application (as part of a war or ear file) or copy them in the server's lib folder.